# Ruby on Rails get google analytics visitors count and save into my app db.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I am working with google analytics to add in my project. i already create account and added js code to my application footer section. Now i want to retrieve visitors information like count, geo etc. I need very specific and simple solution about that.

Answer (score 0):

In app/services/google_analytics.rb file,

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'

class GoogleAnalytics
  def initialize
    @client  = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => ENV['GA_APP_NAME'], :application_version => '1.0')
    key_file = File.join('config', ENV['GA_KEY_FILE_NAME'])
    key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(key_file, 'notasecret')
    service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
      ENV['GA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'],
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'],
      key)
    @client.authorization = service_account.authorize
    @analytics = @client.discovered_api('analytics', 'v3')
  end

  def visitors(startDate, endDate, site_url)
    parameters = {'ids' => "ga:" + ENV['GA_VIEW_ID'],
                  'filters' => "ga:pagePath=~"+ site_url,
                  'start-date' => startDate,
                  'end-date' => endDate,
                  'dimensions' => "ga:country,ga:source",
                  'metrics' => "ga:sessions",
                  'sort' => "-ga:sessions",
                  'include-empty-rows' => false
                }
    results = @client.execute(api_method: @analytics.data.ga.get, parameters: parameters)
    if results.error?
      puts results.error_message
      return [0, {}, {}]
    else
      total_count = 0
      countries = {}
      sources = {}
      results.data.rows.each do |row|
        total_count += row[-1].to_i
        countries[row[0]] = countries[row[0]].to_i + row[-1].to_i
        sources[row[1]] = sources[row[1]].to_i + row[-1].to_i
      end
      return [total_count, countries, sources]
    end
  end

end
```

and in your controller#action, add code like this:

```
ga = ::GoogleAnalytics.new()
@total_visits, @countries, @sources = ga.visitors(start_date, end_date, @user.site_url)
```

It works.